# Is there a FuturesOrdered alternative that yields results one by one?

Tags: rust, async-await, stream, future, rust-tokio

In Rust, I have a bunch of async functions that I want to execute in parallel. The order in which the results of these functions are handled is important. I also want to retrieve the results of these functions as they become available.

Let me explain poorly.

Here is the description of `FuturesOrdered`:

> This "combinator" is similar to FuturesUnordered, but it imposes an
> order on top of the set of futures. While futures in the set will race
> to completion in parallel, results will only be returned in the order
> their originating futures were added to the queue.

So far so good. Now look at this example:

```rust
let mut ft = FuturesOrdered::new();
ft.push(wait_n(1)); // wait_n sleeps
ft.push(wait_n(2)); // for the given
ft.push(wait_n(4)); // number of secs
ft.push(wait_n(3));
ft.push(wait_n(5));
let r = ft.collect::<Vec<u64>>().await;
```

Since `FuturesOrdered` awaits until *all* futures are completed; this is what I get:

```
|--|        ++
|----|      ++
|--------|  ++
|------|    ++
|----------|++
            ++-> all results available here
```

This is what I want:

```
|--|++
|----|++
|--------|++
|------|    ++
|----------|  ++
```

In other words; I want to await on the *next* future; as the remaining futures keep racing to completion. Also note that even though task #4 was completed before task #3; it was handled after #3 because of the initial order.

How can I get a stream of futures that are executed concurrently like this? I was hoping for something like this:

```rust
let mut ft = MagicalStreamOfOrderedFutures::new();
ft.push(wait_n(1));
ft.push(wait_n(2));
ft.push(wait_n(4));
ft.push(wait_n(3));
ft.push(wait_n(5));
while Some(result) = ft.next().await {
  // returns results in order at seconds 1,2,4,4,5
}
```

Comment: Just to be clear - would the `futures::select` (https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/future/fn.select.html) be the thing you need in case of only two futures?

Comment: Doesn't `select` return the result of the first future to complete? I don't want that; I want all results in the order they were started.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Since FuturesOrdered awaits until all futures are completed

It does not inherently do that.

You're asking it to because you're `collect`-ing to a `Vec`. Since the entire point of [`StreamExt::collect`](https://docs.rs/futures/latest/futures/stream/trait.StreamExt.html#method.collect) is to convert *the entire stream* into a collection:

> Transforms a stream into a collection, returning a future representing the result of that computation. The returned future will be resolved when the stream terminates.

It can only yield the collection once all the futures have settled.

If you access the stream lazily, it'll yield items as they become available:

```
let mut s = stream::FuturesOrdered::new();
s.push(future::lazy(|_| 1).boxed());
s.push(future::lazy(|_| panic!("never resolves")).boxed());

let f = s.next().await;
println!("{:?}", f);
```

[works just fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1611fdd06613547f950a8b5f765d076c), despite it not being possible for the second future to resolve. If you try to `collect` it, it'll panic.

> How can I get a stream of futures that are executed concurrently like this? I was hoping for something like this:

[Exactly like that?](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=42d0417797d7e2f2216c732338505884)

```
let mut s = stream::FuturesOrdered::new();
s.push(sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)));
s.push(sleep(Duration::from_millis(200)));
s.push(sleep(Duration::from_millis(400)));
s.push(sleep(Duration::from_millis(300)));
s.push(sleep(Duration::from_millis(500)));

let start = Instant::now();
while s.next().await.is_some() {
    println!("{:.2?}", Instant::now() - start);
}
```

```
101.49ms
200.98ms
400.94ms
400.96ms
501.40ms
```

(using millisecond sleeps because multi-second sleep tends to trip the playground's timeout)